# Eloquent Relationships - hasOneThrough

Tags: laravel, has-one-through

---------- tables ----------

**users**

- user_id

**customers**

- customer_id
- user_id

**schedules**

- schedule_id
- mail_id
- customer_id

**mails**

- mail_id
- subject

--------- models ----------

**schedules_model**

```
public function customer() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'customer_id');
}
public function mail() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Mail', 'mail_id');
}
public function user() 
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(?);
}
```

--------- controllers ----------

```
$schedules = schedules_model->with('customer')->with('mail')->get();
```

Please help me how to get user information through customer ?
Many thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why getting the user information from the schedule directly, you can simply do

```php
$schedules = schedules_model->with('customer.user')->with('mail')->get();
```